# CopiedTxt and CopiedTxt.execCommand doesn't work

Tags: php, button, onclick, copy

I have this code that enable me to copy to clipboard the link of the current page when I click on a button. But it seems that it's no longer working. Any idea how to update it?

```
<?php
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">

function CopyToClipboard()
{
CopiedTxt = index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$articleid.'&lang='.substr($langue, 0, -3).'&Itemid='.$itemid.';
CopiedTxt.execCommand("Copy");
}
</script>
<form name="Form1">
<input type="button" onClick="CopyToClipboard()" value="Copy link to clipboard" />
</form>';
?>
```

Also any other way to copy a text to a clipboard (using PHP/javascript only) is welcome!